# How can I take two rows for one Distinct value in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to get two rows of distinct column2 from following table.

```
demo_table 
id  | column1 | column2
 1  |    1    |    3
 2  |    2    |    3
 3  |    3    |    4
 4  |    4    |    3
 5  |    5    |    4
 6  |    6    |    3
```

When I preform this query

```
select distinct on (column2) * from demo_table
```

it gives me out put as this

```
id  | column1 | column2
 5  |    5    |    4
 6  |    6    |    3
```

I am looking for query where I can get output as

```
id  | column1 | column2
 3  |    3    |    4
 5  |    5    |    4
 6  |    6    |    3
 4  |    4    |    3
```

it should give two row where column2 is distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use row_number() for that:

```
select id, column1, column2
from (
  select id, column1, column2, 
         row_number() over (partition by column2 order by id) as rn
  from demo_table
) t 
where rn <= 2;
```

Comment: i am getting error LINE 4:          row_number() over  ERROR: syntax error at or near "("

Comment: @VikramSangat: I forgot the `from`