# How can I take two rows for one Distinct value with respect to time in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

In continuation to my question [How can I take two rows for one Distinct value in postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718851/how-can-i-take-two-rows-for-one-distinct-value-in-postgresql)

in above question I got solution for my basic problem of taking 2 values from distinct column.

But while working on it, I found a new question

When I introduced a timestamp to my table

```
demo_table 
id  | column1 | column2 |      timestamp
 1  |    1    |    3    | 2016-09-23 00:20:20
 2  |    2    |    3    | 2016-09-24 00:20:20
 3  |    3    |    4    | 2016-09-24 00:20:20
 4  |    4    |    3    | 2016-09-25 00:20:20
 5  |    5    |    4    | 2016-09-25 00:20:20
 6  |    6    |    3    | 2016-09-27 00:20:20
 7  |    7    |    5    | 2016-09-28 00:20:20
 8  |    8    |    5    | 2016-09-28 00:20:20
 9  |    9    |    3    | 2016-09-30 00:20:20
```

the query

```
select id, column1, column2
from (
  select id, column1, column2, 
         row_number() over (partition by column2 order by id) as rn
  from demo_table
) t 
where rn <= 2;
```

did not return what I expected:

```
id  | column1 | column2 |      timestamp
 3  |    3    |    4    | 2016-09-24 00:20:20
 5  |    5    |    4    | 2016-09-25 00:20:20
 6  |    6    |    3    | 2016-09-27 00:20:20
 7  |    7    |    5    | 2016-09-28 00:20:20
 8  |    8    |    5    | 2016-09-28 00:20:20
 9  |    9    |    3    | 2016-09-30 00:20:20
```

I need a query which will give this result:

```
id  | column1 | column2 |      timestamp
 6  |    6    |    3    | 2016-09-27 00:20:20
 9  |    9    |    3    | 2016-09-30 00:20:20
 5  |    5    |    4    | 2016-09-25 00:20:20
 3  |    3    |    4    | 2016-09-24 00:20:20
 7  |    7    |    5    | 2016-09-28 00:20:20
 8  |    8    |    5    | 2016-09-28 00:24:20
```

The table should be distinct on column2 and it should also keep mapping two rows of same value in column together

Is this possible?

Comment: Your expected output is the same as the actual output, save for the order of the rows.

Comment: @redneb no actually if u look at timestamps its changing the order of rows that need to come one after other

Comment: So just add an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: order by will work on above output what if column2 got one more with different value it will again change the output

Comment: @redneb i have changed my table for the query i am looking for

Comment: `order by column2, id` didn't work? Btw. the timestamp is missing in the selection.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want the "2 most recent" rows for each value in column 2. To do that you tweak the `order by` element of the `over clause`.

Here, to get "most recent" rows; order the **timestamp in descending order**. The `id` column is retained in the unlikely event you need a tie-breaker for the order.

```
select id, column1, column2, timestamp
from (
  select id, column1, column2, timestamp,
         row_number() over (partition by column2 order by timestamp DESC, id) as rn
  from demo_table
) t 
where rn <= 2
order by column2, timestamp
;
```

(The final order of the timestamp then alters to ascending)

Note: In the `over clause` it is the `partition by` argument that controls when ordering restarts (when a new "partition" is encountered) and the `order by` then controls which row within a "partition" gets to be 1.